# How to Collect Status of all Upstream Jobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

Suppose I've below hierarchy of Jenkins Job -

TestJob1 -> TestJob11, TestJob2, TestJob3, TestJob4...

And There is Downstream Job "**CollectStatusJob**" and here TestJob1...TestJob4 are configured in "**Project to Watch List**".
[CollectStatusJob Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnxWh.png)

In this CollectStatusJob How can I get the status of all upstream jobs (TestJob1...TestJob4) like accessing environment variables of all upstream Jobs?

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure the default triggering function can do that. You can, however, use the [Parameterized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=36602920#content/view/36602920) and this can pass info to the job it’s triggering, so that job can check it.